# Make prediction for each group differently

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, grouping, forecasting

I have dataset that looks like this:

```
Category Weekly_Date             a             b
   <chr>    <date>           <dbl>         <dbl>
 1   aa     2018-07-01        36.6          1.4
 2   aa     2018-07-02        5.30          0   
 3   bb     2018-07-01        4.62          1.2
 4   bb     2018-07-02        3.71          1.5
 5   cc     2018-07-01        3.41          12
... ...            ...         ...          ...
```

I fitted linear regression for each group separately:

```
fit_linreg <- train %>%
              group_by(Category) %>%
              do(model = lm(Target ~ Unit_price + Unit_discount, data = .))
```

Now I have different models for each category:

```
aa model1
bb model2
cc model3
```

So, I need to apply each model to the appropriate category. How to achieve that? (dplyr is preferable)

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by *"apply each model to the appropriate category"*. You have three models, are you trying to run a prediction?

Comment: Each category of items was sold in some date. So I run regression on each category. So, I have separate models for each category and need to run for category aa model1, bb - model2, etc.

Comment: Again, what does *"need to run for category"* mean? Get the model coefficients? P-values? Epsilon? Use other (test) data and calculate predictions? Calculate predictions with the training data? Print summaries of the models (which includes much of the above)? I'm not being argumentative, to me your "run the model" could mean many things, and though the answer will likely be similar for each, I don't want to spend the time to answer a question you have not asked.

Comment: (Said another way.) If you had a single model for the `aa` category stored as a variable named `model1`, what would you do with it? `coef(model1)`, `predict(model1, newdata)`, `summary(model1)`? Once you know what you want to do with one of the models, then apply that with a `map`, something like `... %>% mutate(summ = purrr::map(model, ~ summary(.)), coefs = purrr::map(model, ~ coef(.)))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you nest the data of your test data, join it with the models, then you can use map2 to make predictions on the test data with the trained models. See below example with mtcars.

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  do(model = lm(mpg ~ hp + wt, data = .)) 

x
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 3 x 2
   gear model   
* <dbl> <list>  
1     3 <S3: lm>
2     4 <S3: lm>
3     5 <S3: lm>

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  nest %>% 
  inner_join(x) %>% 
  mutate(preds = map2(model, data, predict)) %>% 
  unnest(preds)

  Joining, by = "gear"
# A tibble: 32 x 2
    gear preds
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     4  22.0
 2     4  21.2
 3     4  25.1
 4     4  26.0
 5     4  22.2
 6     4  17.8
 7     4  17.8
 8     4  28.7
 9     4  32.3
10     4  30.0
# ... with 22 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach, I'm using `data.table` to filter but you can use `dplyr` instead as well, I just prefer the `data.table` syntax.

```
d <- as.data.table(mtcars)
cats <- unique(d$cyl)

m <- lapply(cats, function(z){
  return(lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + hp + disp, 
            data = d[cyl == z, ] ))
})

names(m) <- cats
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> summary(m)
  Length Class Mode
6 12     lm    list
4 12     lm    list
8 12     lm    list

# Checking first model 
> m[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + hp + disp, data = d[cyl == z, ])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           wt           hp         disp  
   30.27791     -3.89618     -0.01097      0.01610 

> sapply(1:length(m), function(z) return(summary(m[[z]])$adj.r.squared))
[1] 0.4434228 0.5829574 0.3461900
```

I named the list because it might be easier to refer to models by name `aa` or `bb` in your case. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I find the nesting and un-nesting very unnatural, so here's my attempt.

Let's say you want the quality of the model's fit.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(data.frame(r2 = summary(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .))$r.squared))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl    r2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4 0.509
#> 2     6 0.465
#> 3     8 0.423
```

Let's say you want the residuals:

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(data.frame(resid = residuals(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .))))
#> # A tibble: 32 x 2
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>      cyl   resid
#>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1     4 -3.67  
#>  2     4  2.84  
#>  3     4  1.02  
#>  4     4  5.25  
#>  5     4 -0.0513
#>  6     4  4.69  
#>  7     4 -4.15  
#>  8     4 -1.34  
#>  9     4 -1.49  
#> 10     4 -0.627 
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

See `?do` for why you need the embedded `data.frame()`. You'll probably want to include other columns in the result. Not just the grouping variable and the residuals. I can't find a neat way to do this, other than listing them!

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(data.frame(disp = .$disp, 
                qsec = .$qsec,
                resid = residuals(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .))))
#> # A tibble: 32 x 4
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>      cyl  disp  qsec   resid
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1     4 108    18.6 -3.67  
#>  2     4 147.   20    2.84  
#>  3     4 141.   22.9  1.02  
#>  4     4  78.7  19.5  5.25  
#>  5     4  75.7  18.5 -0.0513
#>  6     4  71.1  19.9  4.69  
#>  7     4 120.   20.0 -4.15  
#>  8     4  79    18.9 -1.34  
#>  9     4 120.   16.7 -1.49  
#> 10     4  95.1  16.9 -0.627 
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

---

### Something that doesn't work

For the first example, I thought the following would work:

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(r2 = summary(lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .))$r.squared)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl    r2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4 0.753
#> 2     6 0.753
#> 3     8 0.753
```

But you can see all models have the same r2. It's because the model is being fit to all the data, not per `cyl`. Looking at the authors' code, I believe this is because they've optimised the evaluation of `mutate()` and `summarise()` using Rcpp, and the optimisation doesn't work in this case. But `do()` works as expected. It subsets the data by group before passing it to the expression to be evaluated. I see they are pondering this, see [Hyrbid Folding](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/bbcfe99e29fe737d456b0d7adc33d3c445a32d9d/vignettes/future/dplyr_0.8.0.Rmd)